# Connection with rest-API and SQL server or Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a problem with the connection to my database located in Azure, I was attempting to do a connection with a rest-API that I create, to a database that I have in Azure, this database I manage directly from SQL Server, and I can't make a connection with this.

I attempt to connect with another test database in SQL Server.

The rest-API ia create is in NodeJS

```js
var sql = require('mssql');
var dbconfig = {
    server:"Fernando\EQUIPO",
    user: "<user>",
    password: "<password>",
    database: "<dbname>",
    port: 1433,
    option: {
        encrypt: false
    }
};

function getList() {
    var record;
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig);
    conn.connect(function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        req.query("select * from cliente", function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) throw err;
            else {
                console.log(recordset);
                record = recordset;
            }
            conn.close();
        });
    });
    return record;
}

const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

const _ = require('underscore');

const movies = require('../sample.json');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(getList());
});
```

When I make a "get" to my local host http://localhost:3000/api/movies appears the following message in the console:

```
GET /api/movies 200 126.188 ms - -
(node:11868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to FernandoEQUIPO:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND FernandoEQUIPO
    at Connection.tedious.once.err (C:\Users\luisn\Desktop\rest-API\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:68:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\luisn\Desktop\rest-API\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1258:12)
    at _connector.Connector.execute (C:\Users\luisn\Desktop\rest-API\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1084:21)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap._dns.default.lookup [as callback] (C:\Users\luisn\Desktop\rest-API\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:152:16)        
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:68:17)
(node:11868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11868) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

```sh
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to FernandoEQUIPO:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND FernandoEQUIPO
```

Your error states that it is unable to connect as it could not find a server at the given address.Make sure there is a server runninng and verify connection using some third party app.
**Are you sure FernandoEQUIPO gets resolved to a proper hostname ?**

Comment: My server name is Fernando\EQUIPO

Comment: I thibk you need to enter your server ip here

Comment: You're right, this resolve my problem and also i change the ports of my server, thank you

Comment: In azure, what ip i have to put?

Comment: @Fernando if this helped you you should accept it as answer, that is how when someone else comes looking for the same question, he knows what to do. :)

Comment: @Fernando In azure, put ip of the sql server just as before, if running locally on the vm, then localhost, else the ip of sql server hosted elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

**Connect to Azure SQL database:**

Here's the example code connect to Azure SQL database with REST-API:
[image]

> **Note: the `encrypt` must be `true`**.

You can get the server name from on Portal:
[image]

And you need to add the client IP address to the [Azure SQL Server firewall settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule):
[image]

Then you could connect to the Azure SQL database now. You can reference:[Creating a Node.js REST API in Azure](https://help.insight.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/140)

**Connect to  SQL Server:**

Your code is almost correct and need some change:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var dbconfig = {
    server:"localhost",
    user: "<user>",
    password: "<password>",
    database: "<dbname>",
    port: 1433,
    option: {
        encrypt: false
    }
};
```

Like  Abhishek Ranjan said, you should enter your server ip.

Hope this helps.